# I want to display bootstrap datepicker using angular 8

Tags: angular8

Using angular 8 I want to display bootstrap datepicker. I want the same datepicker to be displayed in my page

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Install bootstrap-datepicker using command of **npm i bootstrap-datepicker**
2. After installation add **"node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"** and "**node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"** in `angular.json`
3. add this code `<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker"><input type="text" class="form-control"><div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></div></div>`

For more information visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: $(...).datepicker is not a function